# Horizontal scrolling within a div

Tags: css

I have the current css:

```
#inner { 
    height: 50em;
    width : 20em;
    overflow: auto;
    float : left;
    padding :10px;
    margin : 20px;
    white-space: normal;
}

#outer{
    width: 60em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border: 13px solid #bed5cd;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

My html code looks like:

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">
data
</div>
<div id="inner">
data
</div>
<div id="inner">
data
</div>
. . . .
</div>
```

I could able to see horizontal scrolling. But the problem is, I don't want to hard code `outer.width` as `60em`. I want to keep it as `auto`. But that ends in vertical scrolling.

Any idea where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: At first you can't have same `id` multiple time in a single web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow:auto` on outer div.

Set `display:inline-block` on inner div, and remove `float`.

```css
#outer {
  border: 13px solid #bed5cd;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#inner {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 20em;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    data
  </div>
  <div id="inner">
    data
  </div>
  <div id="inner">
    data
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply below css class on the div

```
.scrolls {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 80px;
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

Comment: on which div? please let me know

Comment: add that css to outer div.